# Delete Term via edit-tags.php

Tags: taxonomy, terms, categories, customization

I might get rep'ed down on this - but is there suppose to be a "Delete" link on the edit-tags.php page? Note: not the WP-List-Table, but the actual page where you specifically view the terms individually.

It seems as if they added on the option here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9777#no1

_*_* UPDATE

It seems like I was looking at the wrong WP file. The individual term page is located at: wp-admin/edit-tag-form.php, and there is no mention of any "Delete".

Knowing this, is it possible to add on a delete button to this page OR creating a "Delete" column onto the WP-List-Table. I tried it this way, but received an "undefined variable 'tag'" for the column.

Here is what I tried:

```
add_filter( 'manage_customcpt_custom_column', 'customcpt_taxnomy_add_columns', 10, 3 );
function saloncms_product_cpt_taxnomy_add_columns( $columns, $column, $id ) {
    if ( $column == 'delete' ) {
    "<a class='delete-tag' href='" . wp_nonce_url( "edit-tags.php?action=delete&amp;taxonomy=$taxonomy&amp;tag_ID=$tag->term_id", 'delete-tag_' . $tag->term_id ) . "'>" . __( 'Delete' ) . "</a>";
    }
    return $columns;
}
```

Thanks,
Roc.

Answer (score 0):

```
"<a class='delete-tag' href='" . wp_nonce_url( "edit-tags.php?action=delete&amp;taxonomy=$taxonomy&amp;tag_ID=$tag->term_id", 'delete-tag_' . $tag->term_id ) . "'>" . __( 'Delete' ) . "</a>";
```

**$tag->term_id**

It's exactly what it says, where did you define $tag?
Also, I'm assuming $id is the $tag->term_id, so you might want to use $id instead.